# Line Break Between Two Floated Div Tags

Tags: css

I have two div tags with the following CSS configured for each respectively. I've changed the width to 100% and added block to the display of each but they insist on being side by side of each other on even mobile devices.  How do I force a line break between these two div tags

```
    <div class="advert-input">
    <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="What are you looking for? ..." value="">
    </div>
    <div class="advert-input">
    <select name="category" style="font-size:18px !important; font-weight:bold;">
    <option value="">All Locations </option>
</select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.adverts-search .advert-input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1.5% 1% 1.5% 1%;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

adverts-search .advert-input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1.5% 1% 1.5% 1%;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please, which would include the divs you speak of

Comment: it's because of that float... get rid of it - no one really uses float anymore :)

Comment: `float` and `display:block` contradict one another, and `float` takes precedence since it comes after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float:left` overrides `display:block`, the easiest way to fix your code is to remove the float property as it essentially says "Go as far left as you can without crashing into your container or into another floated property, and use `display:inline`" Since the float property is after the display property, the float property has priority.

The best solution is by far to remove the float property, as float can do all kinds of similarly frustrating results.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `float: left;`, this will make them display one under the other.